# Backbone views not rendering without predefined el specified

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

What I am trying to do is create views which can be removable without removing the parent element. I've found that when I set the `el` property directly on the View, when I `.remove()` it, the parent element is also removed.

I've tried creating a view with just a `tagName` thinking it will just pop it into `body`, but this is not the case, it doesn't seem to insert it into the page at all.

What's the correct way to completely remove a view from an element without removing the actual containing element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the "parent element" is `el`.

```
var DemoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#container",
    events: {
        "click button": "removeSelf"
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.append("<button>remove</button>");
        return this;
    },
    removeSelf: function () {
        this.remove();
    }
});
new DemoView().render();
```

if you click the button,`#container` will be removed;if you don't want the `#container` to be removed,just not set the `el` property,and the DemoView will create an empty `div`,just like this:

```
var DemoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click button": "removeSelf"
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.append("<button>remove</button>");
        return this;
    },
    removeSelf: function () {
        this.remove();
    }
});
var demoView = new DemoView();
$("#container").append(demoView.render().el);
```

now,if you click the button,demoView will be removed,but the `#container` will not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify default el, you have to append them to an element later like `view.render().$el.appendTo('body')`. body can be any other selector which points to the container element.